# Accord du participe passé avec le COD et l'auxiliaire "avoir"

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé

**Question**

First i would like to have an explanation of how this grammar works:

> Tu as acheté un cadeau pour votre amie ?

**Answer**

The answer is supposed to be:

> Oui, je l'ai acheté.

I chose *oui, je l'ai achetee*, which is incorrect.

Please explain how my answer is incorrect.

**Where my confusion happens**

> Tu as acheté un cadeau pour votre amie ?

The answer to that is supposed to be:

> Oui, je l'ai acheté

How is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you heard about the rule of past participle agreement with the direct object complement, if you're asking such a question, so I'm not going to explain it in details. Let's just see why it's not *-ée*:

> Oui je **l**'ai acheté. / Yes, I bought **it**.

... *l'* is for *it* and it refers to *le cadeau*, which is masculine. You don't want to make the past participle agree with *amie* here.

Note that with the question *Tu as acheté un cadeau pour votre amie ?*, since it's *un cadeau* and not *le cadeau*, the answer should better be: *Oui, j'en ai acheté un* (*I bought one*).

Answer (score 3):

*To complete the @Simon Déchamps's answer*

When you do not know to what it refers you can use this trick :

The sentence :

> Oui je **l**'ai acheté/achetée *(is "l" masculine or feminine ?)*

Ask yourself :

> Oui j'ai acheté **quoi** ? J'ai acheté **le cadeau**

You now know what is the object. In this case it is a masculine word then you do not add the *"e"*

> Oui je l'ai acheté !

Answer (score 0):

*Accord avec l'auxiliaire avoir*

Le participe passé ne s'accorde jamais avec le sujet lorsqu'il est employé avec l'auxiliaire avoir:

for example : elles ont mangé au restaurant du coin.

It means that when you have a phrase with the verb 'avoir' the past participle never agrees with the subject and it's always "e" and NEVER "ée"

For example : j'ai acheté une fleur. J'ai acheté un coffre.

Comment: Unless COD is placed before the verb.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Il y a une [rubrique d'aide](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) pour en expliquer le fonctionnement. "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? ". La question n'est pas sur l'accord du participe passé avec le sujet, il est clair que celui qui posé la question sait que l'accord ne se fait pas avec le sujet.   *it's always "e" and NEVER "ée*, what about past participles ending with *i* or *u*?