# Accord participe passé + pronom

Tags: participe-passé

Bonjour

dans la phrase "j'ai une pensée pour les personnes qui nous ont encouragé", comment accorder le verbe encourager ?

Merci

Comment: Avec le complément d'objet direct (nous) qui est placé avant, soit  « encouragés »

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-avec-un-pronom-relatif & https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22161/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-avec-le-cod-et-lauxiliaire-avoir discutent aussi de ce genre de problème.

Answer (score 2):

Les personnes ont encouragé **qui** ? **Nous!**

Le complément d'objet direct *nous* est placé avant le verbe avoir.

L'accord se fait donc avec *nous*. Le participe passé doit être au pluriel. Il sera souvent au masculin mais devra être au féminin si seuls des sujets féminins sont présents dans ce *nous*.

Un homme parlant au nom de plusieurs personnes dont éventuellement des femmes :

> J'ai une pensée pour les personnes qui nous ont encouragés.

Une femme parlant au nom de plusieurs femmes:

> J'ai une pensée pour les personnes qui nous ont encouragées.

Il est néanmoins très courant de lire :

> J'ai une pensée pour les personnes qui nous ont encouragé.

L'absence d'accord est encore aujourd'hui considéré comme une erreur sauf dans les cas très rares où il s'agit d'un [*nous* de majesté](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nous_de_majest%C3%A9) ou un [*nous* de modestie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nous_de_modestie).

Comment: Il est néanmoins très courant de lire :

    J'ai une pensée pour les personnes qui nous ont encouragé.                                                                                                                            Est-ce à dire que c'est une erreur ou les deux conjugaisons sont correctes ?

Comment: @Olivier Stricto sensu, c'est une erreur (sauf dans les rares cas où il s'agit d'un *nous* de majesté ou de modestie), mais elle est tellement courante que la règle finira certainement un jour ou l'autre par se relâcher.