# "N'arrêtez pas de prendre ces gélules tous les matins que le médecin vous a donné..." or "...données..."?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, subordonnées

Is this sentence grammatically correct in French:

> N'arrêtez pas de prendre ces gélules tous les matins que le médecin
>   vous a donné...?

Which one is correct: "...gélules que le médecin vous a **donné**" or "...gélules que le médecin vous a **données**"?

Comment: Neither one nor the other! In your sentence, the relative pronoun *que* refers to *matins* which is masculine plural => ***donnés*** would be the only grammatically correct option. (While being semantically absurd, I'll easily acknowledge that!)

Comment: "N'arrêtez pas de prendre tous les matins ces gélules que le médecin vous a données" would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a relative clause *que le médecin vous a données*. The antecedent *que* must be right after the noun it represents (*gélules*).

The time clause *tous les matins* can go either before or after the relative clause.

Concerning the agreement of the past participle there are already answers about that you can look at, for instance [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22161/358). You'll find more by browsing the [[participe-passé] + avoir tag](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bparticipe-pass%C3%A9%5D%20avoir).

Comment: I think  "can go either before or after the relative clause" can be misleading: It should rather be "can go either before or after the antecedent AND the relative clause".

Comment: Je pense que vous vous trompez sur la défintion d'antécedent: l'antécédent est le nom auquel se rapporte le pronom relatif: c'est donc ici *gélules* et non *que*. (cf 1ère source: Elle (la proposition relative) complète un nom ou un pronom appelé antécédent et dont elle est une expansion.)