# Utilisation correcte du verbe manquer

Tags: verbes, accord

Un homme peut dire:

```
Bergerac m'a manqué.
```

et aussi

```
La Tour Eiffel m'a manqué
```

Mais, une femme dit-elle

```
Bergerac m'a manquée/La Tour Eiffel m'a manquée?
```

Entre deux femmes, dirait-on `À ma chère, vous m'avez manquée`?

En effet, ma question est s'il y a un accord avec l'objet indirect quand on utilise le verbe `manquer` dans ce sens.

Il me semble que même pour les femmes, ca devrait être `Bergerac m'a manqué/La Tour Eiffel m'a manqué` (sans `e` final), mais je ne suis pas tout à fait sûr de moi. Explications je vous pris.

<sup>Si jamais j'ai fait de fautes de français, je serais reconnaissant si vous auriez la gentilesse de les corriger</sup>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accord du participe passé avec le COD et l'auxiliaire "avoir"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22161/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-avec-le-cod-et-lauxiliaire-avoir)

Comment: L'accord ne se fait **jamais** avec l'objet indirect quel que soit le verbe. Manquer n'est pas une exception.

Comment: @None ce dernier commentaire mériterait d'être une réponse (validée)

Answer (score 3):

Si tu étais une femme que l'archer Bergerac avait vainement essayé  de t'atteindre avec ses flèches, tu aurais pu dire **Bergerac m'a manquée** (a manqué **qui** ? **Toi** : COD placé avant le verbe).

Sinon, pas d'accord (a manqué **à qui** ? **À toi** : COI).

Comment: @jillagre - Étant donné que je suis un homme, cela m'étonnerait que je mette un `e` supplémentaire à la fin de `manqué`! :-)

Comment: Ah oui, ça ne marche plus. J'ajuste le tir ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*, l'accord est avec le COD, s'il est placé avant le verbe. Donc, il suffit de trouver la place du COD et son genre pour décider s'il faut accorder le participe passé ou non. L'accord n'est pas avec le sujet du verbe, donc le genre du/de la locuteur/locutrice n'intervient pas avec cet auxiliaire.

Le cas de la voix passive peut être un peu plus compliqué à décoder, mais la règle est la même: https://www.salle34.net/laccord-du-participe-passe-cas-complexes/.

Comment: Mais justement, je ne suis pas sûr du cas qui s'applique ici?